# Migrating a website from OpenCms to LIferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, opencms, liferay-theme

A website is currently in OpenCms which needs to be migrated to Liferay framework as is.

There is a concept of JSP templates in OpenCms. Is it possible to replicate the concept of jsp templates which is present in OpenCms into themes/layouts in liferay?

OpenCms templates use cms tags like `<cms: />`

How will it be possible for me to transfer this entire website from OpenCms into Liferay?

I have googled a lot regarding this but I did not get any answer for this.

Help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is some more info regarding the project:

The website has static as well as dynamic pages. I need a way to recreate them in liferay so that in future if the users wish to change the data content of website they can do so easily. IN case of dynamic pages they will upate their database. IN case of static pages they would want to change data (if required) from liferay framework.

How should I create templates and add pages that use a particular template and also add content to the pages?

SHould I write a code or can I do directly from the liferay UI ? Is there a quick way to do this?

I tried using ftl templates. But will it be useful or should I create templates from liferay?

Comment: what does the `<cms: />` tag or a jsp template actually do in OpenCms?

Comment: @Olaf Kock:
Hi Olaf thanks for prompt reply. In opencms they have a concept of building jsp templates where they have their own opencms tags such as <cms:template element="head"> , <cms:template element="body">
<cms:include element="body" /> etc.
My main requirement is to migrate a website which is currently in  opencms to liferay. THey have created some templates to be used in opencms. how should i replicate them in lifeeray? I was thinking of using themes and layoputs that we have in liferay. But i do not have idea how to start with this. can you provide some help?

Comment: @Olaf Kock:
What I wana ask is will it be possible for me to migrate from opencms to liferay?

Comment: The short answer is "yes, of course you can migrate", see below for the long answer

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with OpenCms, but Liferay's CMS has structured articles that get rendered by templates, e.g. freemarker or velocity templates. From what I read into your question and comment, this might be what you're looking for:

Identify the elements of your content articles in OpenCms, create appropriate structures in Liferay and import the articles into structured articles, using those structures. Further, create templates that render the HTML output as you need it from the imported articles.

You'll probably also want to create pages (layouts in the Liferay API) and populate them with the corresponding content. Almost all of Liferay's functionality is available through an API - and it's well possible to import content through this API (in fact, that's a common usecase). I can't help you with the best way to read OpenCms content though.

For getting used to the Liferay CMS API I was recommending the sevencogs demo for a long time. Unfortunately this is no longer maintained, but there's a [blog article](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) summarizing many of the calls and API usages that you might want to make use of.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a lead. I will try the approach that you have suggested and will keep you updated. I had posted this ques in liferay forum but did not get any reply.. I have upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: I had used freemarker templates previosly for a portal development for sending mails based on a condition. Can I make use of the same templates here so that I can use them instead of opencms jsp templates for migration?

Comment: @ Prakash K : 
Can you give me some ideas as to how should I go about this problem?
SHould I programaticaly create templates using java functions or create using the liferay interface provided? Help will be appreciated.
I have updated my ques