# Replicate pages from OpenCms to Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, opencms, liferay-theme

I know this is a duplicate post but I needed help here. I had posted about my query before on how should I approach to migrate a website which is currently in OpenCms into Liferay.

I will share whatever I have found on internet and a reply that I got in one of the forums here on stackoverflow.

I was suggested to use ftl templates. but won't it be like executing the code everytime the user makes changes to a web page?

The website has static as well as dynamic pages. I need a way to recreate them in liferay so that in future if the users wish to change the data content of website they can do so easily. IN case of dynamic pages they will upate their database. IN case of static pages they would want to change data (if required) from liferay framework.

How should I create templates and add pages that use a particular template and also add content to the pages?

SHould I write a code or can I do directly from the liferay UI ? Is there a quick way to do this?

Regards

Comment: If your other question hasn't been fully answered, please refine the question rather than asking it again, even announcing that you willingly post a duplicate. Plus, speaking of "dynamic" vs "static" pages in a context of migrating from a CMS to a Portal is not quite enough information to base any recommendation on. Recommendation: Manually build a prototype for your new site on Liferay, if you know what exactly you want, decide for scripted (automatic) or manual migration of the whole site. In order to fully use Liferay, you'll have to have *some* experience with it - no shortcut, sorry.

Comment: @OlafKock:
I had used liferay to build a portal before but here I am finding difficulty in migrating a website from opencms to liferay.
Thanks for prompt replies though..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating a website from OpenCms to LIferay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450268/migrating-a-website-from-opencms-to-liferay)